# Where is $|z|^ae^{iaArg(z)}$ differentiable?

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose that $a\in \mathbb{R}$,
Use the polar form of the Cauchy-Riemann equations to find where $|z|^ae^{iaArg(z)}$ is differentiable. Here Arg is the principal argument whose range is $(-\pi,\pi]$.

Letting $z=re^{i\theta}$, $|z|^ae^{iaArg(z)}=r^a\cos a\theta+ir^a\sin a\theta$. Then
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}=ar^{a-1}\cos a\theta \\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial \theta}=-ar^{a}\sin a\theta \\
\frac{\partial v}{\partial r}=ar^{a-1}\sin a\theta \\
\frac{\partial v}{\partial \theta}=ar^{a}\cos a\theta \\
$$
I know the equations hold however they also have to be defined and continuous. I am having doubts on finding where they are defined and continous.

For example if $a>1$, then since all the powers of $r$ are positive, it seems that the partial derivatives are continuous everywhere, however that can't be true since Arg(0) is not defined.